# Is it possible to import all audio date at once into rythmbox?

Tags: music

does anybody know how to import the music files all at once into rythmbox even if
they´re in different folders?
I have to confess that I´m lazy. :-D

Thanks
Florian

Answer (score 0):

You can create symlinks from all folders into one and set it as a root of your collection.
But Rhythmbox and Juk are very basic players. Take something more advanced, like Clementine, where GUI options support multiple collections.

Comment: You can specify multiple directories as library paths in Rhythmbox. The UI only supports selecting one, but you can set a list of multiple in _dconf-editor_ or with _gsettings_ on the console.